# Не запускается Debian, bios не видит hdd в boot

Tags: linux, debian, bios

Всем привет!

Возникла проблема с запуском Debian.

Проблема заключается в следующем: поставил на свой ноут (Asus x550cc) Debian все работало хорошо.

Потом возникла необходимость разобрать ноут, пришлось вытащить HDD. После того как все было собрано обратно Linux перестал запускаться.

Сразу выбивает в BIOS где boot optiob priorities пустой, но в SATA configuration диск отображается. Диск ТОЧНО исправен и подключен правильно. Так уверен в этом потому что эта проблема возникает не в первый раз, до этого она решалась повторной установкой ОС, но теперь хочется все таки это поченить.

Настройки BIOS в дефолт уже сносил, не помогло.
Как быть?

Comment: А может так оказаться, что дефолтовые настройки биоса у Вашего ноута - это UEFI + Secure boot?  И ожидает он увидеть только загрузчик винды? И есть еще возможность, что Ваш Debian установлен на раздел с MBR, и вообще без UEFI...

Comment: говоря о своих шиках, попался мне один раз intel'овский bios, который отказывался грузиться с винта, если на нём не было раздела помеченного boot-флагом... может аналогичный случай?

Comment: А как поправить то?

Comment: Если не знаете, какая таблица разделов и какой загрузчик установлен, то тогда остается только перебирать возможные варианты в биосе. Если включен Secure boot - его отключить в первую очередь (насколько помню, с ним линух не живет)... Можно попробовать загрузиться с флешки (или DVD) и посмотреть, какая таблица разделов. Если GPT, то тогда однозначно в биосе нужно включить поддержку UEFI.

Comment: @Vladimir, grub прекрасно умеет грузиться с GPT без всяких UEFI...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, про grub вполне верю. Но не уверен, что это распространенная практика. Ибо на современных машинах ради этого нужно лезть в биос и искать, как включить Legacy режим загрузки.

Comment: Загрузитесь с любого Live/CD или флэшки и посмотрите - виден ли ваш  HDD вообще. Дальнейшее - по обстоятельствам...